# How to fix Drake C++ Mac bazel build error

Tags: drake

I am trying to install latest Drake from source on Macbook Pro M1. I have mac os ventura 13.3.1.

The bazel build fails on the following error (I need bazel for unit tests etc.):

```
drew@drews-MacBook-Pro-3 drake % bazel run -j 10 --config=mosek --config=gurobi //:install -- ~/drake-build --no_strip
INFO: Analyzed target //:install (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/drew/corporate/drake/bindings/pydrake/BUILD.bazel:452:22: GenerateMypyStubs bindings/pydrake/pydrake/autodiffutils.pyi failed: (Exit 1): stubgen failed: error executing command (from target //bindings/pydrake:pydrake_pyi) bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/pydrake/autodiffutils.pyi bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/pydrake/common/__init__.pyi ... (remaining 36 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
CRITICAL:drake:Could not initialize pydrake: ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

At:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py(135): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(940): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(705): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1151): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1178): _find_and_load
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/common/_common_extra.py(8): <module>
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/__init__.py(74): _execute_extra_python_code
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(1233): create_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(573): module_from_spec
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(676): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1149): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1178): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1234): _handle_fromlist
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/__init__.py(163): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(940): exec_module
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(690): _load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1149): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1178): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1206): _gcd_import
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1128): _find_and_load_unlocked
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1178): _find_and_load
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1206): _gcd_import
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1285): __import__
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py(29): _pydrake_modules
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py(109): _actual_main
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py(154): _wrapper_main
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py(158): <module>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/usr/local/bin/python3.11"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/__init__.py", line 74, in _execute_extra_python_code
    exec(_code, m.__dict__, m.__dict__)
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/common/_common_extra.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py", line 158, in <module>
    sys.exit(_wrapper_main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py", line 154, in _wrapper_main
    return _actual_main()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py", line 109, in _actual_main
    native_modules = _pydrake_modules()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.py", line 29, in _pydrake_modules
    importlib.__import__("pydrake._all_everything")
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1285, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_drew/8e7fb6d5be1ace4aa9f7d9cb5d45abf6/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/3903/execroot/drake/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from . import common
ImportError: initialization failed
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /Users/drew/corporate/drake/BUILD.bazel:121:8 Middleman _middlemen/install-runfiles failed: (Exit 1): stubgen failed: error executing command (from target //bindings/pydrake:pydrake_pyi) bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/stubgen bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/pydrake/autodiffutils.pyi bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/pydrake/common/__init__.pyi ... (remaining 36 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.663s, Critical Path: 1.43s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
```

The same error persisted after reinstalling numpy:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you run the install_prereqs script? https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html#mandatory-platform-specific-instructions ? Drake install numpy from homebrew on mac (not pip). If not, then please give us more information about which installation method you're using.

Comment: Yes I ran the install_prereqs script. I used the default numpy but it gave this bug so I reinstalled with pip.

Comment: I just uninstalled numpy and ran the install_prereqs again, with the same error

Comment: Supposing my system got bricked somehow by a broken install, is there anyway to undo the install_prereqs / remove everything and try from scratch?

Comment: I can confirm that 1.26.2 is the version of numpy that I run successfully on my mac m1.

Comment: ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')),

Comment: I checked the numpy and python version, both are arm64. seems the install script is very broken

Comment: is there any way to undo everything in the install_prereqs script and try again?

Comment: I think a big part of the problem is the drake bazel install is not handling things correctly between multiple versions of python, the default 3.9 and the 3.11 it tries to install. For example, there are no headers for 3.11 included in the headers generated by xcode